# How to match regex literal string '.*'

Tags: regex, literals

I wonder how to match the literal string ' .* '?
the ' .* ' is simply the string to search, not carrying any meaning in regex. Thanks.

Comment: Why use a regex when you're looking for a literal string?

Comment: this is only part of the string I want to search, for the remaining pattern, I figured out this, and not sure for '.*' part only

Comment: I don't understand those who downvote this. Anyone mind explaining this? Is this because of I haven't tried anything? Or is this question of low quality?

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape the sequence:

`\.\*`

Comment: I forget to mention using C#

Comment: like you would any other C# regex, but escaping the sequence like I showed.

Comment: With C# you need to put an @ symbol before the string so that your backslashes don't get escaped by C#, eg myregex = @"\.\*"

Answer (score 3):

You will have to escape it

```
'\.\*'
```

When working with C# you should consider using

```
Regex.Escape()
```

before using external input as part of a regular expression